# Handle Settings in Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, I fixed my problem with a public ViewModel for my MainPage like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
private static MainPageVM Data = new MainPageVM();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;

    this.DataContext = Data;

    this.SizeChanged += (s, args) =>
    {
        PageSizeChanged();
    };

    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged += (a, o) =>
    {
        CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Data.Theme = (int)ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
        });
    };
}
```

MainPageVM.cs:

```cs
private void SetValues()
{
    if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Theme"))
    {
        int value = (int)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
        if (value >= 0 && value <= 2) { Theme = value; }
        else { Theme = 0; }
    }
    else { Theme = 0; }
}

private int _theme = 0;
public int Theme
{
    get { return _theme; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _theme) return;
        _theme = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Settings.xaml.cs:

```cs
private void InitSettings()
{
    if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Theme"))
    {
        int value = (int)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
        if (value >= 0 && value <= 2) { Theme.SelectedIndex = value; }
        else { Theme.SelectedIndex = 0; }
    }
    else { Theme.SelectedIndex = 0; }
}

private void ThemeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"] = Theme.SelectedIndex;
    ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
}
```

Settings.xaml:

```xml
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Margin="0,5">Text and background color:</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox Name="Theme" SelectionChanged="ThemeChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Black on White/Purple" Foreground="Black" Background="White"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="White on Black/White" Foreground="White" Background="Black"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Black on White/Gold" Foreground="Black" Background="White"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

There is similar code for each setting, but this is a good representation of it.  It doesn't feel right to use an `int` to represent my theme; should this be an `enum`?  Please tell me all the problems now so I don't have to refactor again later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really like the dependencies on all that static stuff. It effectively means your code becomes very hard to test.

Also this code:

> ```
> if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Theme"))
> {
>     int value = (int)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
>     if (value >= 0 && value <= 2) { Theme = value; }
>     else { Theme = 0; }
> }
> else { Theme = 0; }
> ```

seems repeated and should be consolidated into a single method.

I'd start cleaning it up by introducing an `IThemeProvider` which can be injected into your `MainPage`, `MainPageVM` and `Settings` classes. Would probably look like this:

```
class ThemeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly int NewTheme;

    public ThemeChangedEventArgs(int newTheme)
    {
        NewTheme = newTheme;
    }
}

interface IThemeProvider
{
    int GetCurrentTheme();
    void SetCurrentTheme(int theme);
    event EventHandler<ThemeChangedEventArgs> ThemeChanged;
}
```

Then your `MainPage` would look something like this:

```
private MainPageVM Data = new MainPageVM();
private IThemeProvider _ThemeProvider;

public MainPage(IThemeProvider themeProvider)
{
    _ThemeProvider = themeProvider;

    this.InitializeComponent();
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;

    this.DataContext = Data;

    this.SizeChanged += (s, args) => PageSizeChanged()
    _ThemeProvider.ThemeChanged += (s, e) => Data.Theme = e.NewTheme;
}
```

`MainPageVM`:

```
private IThemeProvider _ThemeProvider; 
public MainPageVM(IThemeProvider themeProvider)
{
    _ThemeProvider = themeProvider;
}

private void SetValues()
{
    Theme = _ThemeProvider.GetCurrentTheme();
}
```

and `Settings`:

```
private IThemeProvider _ThemeProvider; 
public Settings(IThemeProvider themeProvider)
{
    _ThemeProvider = themeProvider;
}

private void InitSettings()
{
    Theme.SelectedIndex = _ThemeProvider.GetCurrentTheme();
}

private void ThemeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _ThemeProvider.SetCurrentTheme(Theme.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Code looks a lot cleaner now I'd say and you can easily mock the `IThemeProvider` out and test it.

Implementation of the provider could be like this (based on what you currently do):

```
public class ApplicationDataThemeProvider : IThemeProvider
{
    public ApplicationDataThemeProvider()
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged += (a, o) =>
        {
            CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                OnThemeChanged((int)ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"]);
            });
        };
    }

    public int GetCurrentTheme()
    {
        if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Theme"))
        {
            int value = (int)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
            return (value >= 0 && value <= 2) ? value : 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void SetCurrentTheme(int theme)
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"] = theme;
        ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ThemeChangedEventArgs> ThemeChanged;
    private void OnThemeChanged(int newTheme)
    {
        var handler = ThemeChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ThemeChangedEventArgs(newTheme));
        }
    }
}
```

This encapsulates all the nasty global app data stuff in a single class where it should be a lot easier to handle and debug.